# Check if boolean is true from another script/scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, scene-manager

I'm writing a code in unity where the player clicks on a mousetrap, which sets the boolean mousetrap = true and increases its value to 1. That is attached to a gameobject called Trap. When I click on another gameobject in another scene, I want it to transition to another scene.

Collection of items (Collect.cs):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MouseCollect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int trap = 0;
    public  bool mousetrap;  

       void Start()
    {
        mousetrap = false;   
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
            if(gameObject.tag == "Trap")
        {
            trap++;
            mousetrap = true;
            GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
        }
        
    }

   
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Script I want to have it referenced in (Mouse.cs)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Mouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        //GameObject.Find("Trap").GetComponent<MouseCollect>().mousetrap;
        if (GameObject.Find("Trap").GetComponent<MouseCollect>().mousetrap && gameObject.tag == "MouseArea")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(10);
        }
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

It doesn't work and it gives me nullreferenceexception. I'm pretty new to Unity and C# so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this part inside the `Update()`

```
if (GameObject.Find("Trap").GetComponent<MouseCollect>().mousetrap && gameObject.tag == "MouseArea")
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(10);
}
```

For a better way, instead of using this inside the update function, try to use this inside `OnTriggerEnter2D()`

[OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)